# cell boundary line issue when using multirow + shortstack

Tags: tables, multirow, shortstack

I am attempting to create a table that makes use of four consecutive multi-rows (if the reason for why this format has been chosen is important I can add it). I am using the multirow package as well as the shortstack command to execute linebreaks in each row. The text in the table is displaying as it should, but the cell boundaries are behaving as if the table was a group of single line rows.

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Name} & \multirow{3}{*}{Website} & \multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack[c]{e-mail \\ phone}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack{line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result is sad:

[image]

Due to the simplicity of the input, I'm quite stumped. I would be greatly appreciative if someone can tell me why this is happening or recommend a smoother way of accomplishing my goal.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the role of `\multirow` in a table that only has one row?

Comment: @marmot, there will be many of these multirow rows. I was using a singular row to illustrate my issue.

Comment: Yes, but this is precisely the reason why it does not work as you want it to work. If you use multirow, you want to make sure that you have multiple rows. At least for the example you show, `makecell` might be a better choice. (As for the example you do not show, I can't say much since [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen.;-)

Comment: I  misunderstood your first comment! having read your answer I understand the meaning of "one row". Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "the text is displaying as it should" I take that you are looking for `makecell`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Name & Website & 
\makecell{e-mail \\ phone} & 
\makecell{line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you *can* do the same with multirow *provided* you really have multiple rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Name} & \multirow{3}{*}{Website} & \multirow{3}{*}{\shortstack[c]{e-mail \\ phone}} & line 1 \\ 
& & & line 2 \\ 
& & & line 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Possible issues with `\shortstack` are discussed in [egreg's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452045/121799).

Comment: Thank you, \makecell is exactly what I need. I will also change the title of my post to something more humble.

Answer (score 3):

The following example shows why `\shortstack` should not be used and proposes a solution for your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\notshortstack}[2][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

% why \shortstak should not be used
\fbox{\shortstack{line 1 \\ aaa \\ line 3}}
\fbox{\shortstack{ling 1 \\ aaa \\ line 3}}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Name & Website & \notshortstack[c]{e-mail \\ phone} &
\notshortstack{line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Ironically, `\longstack` would be shorter than `\nonshortstack` ;-) (And isn't that (more or less) what `\makecell` does?

Comment: @marmot `makecell` can do much more; it mostly depends on what one has to do.